# Weird Exception with SQL Compact Edition

Tags: debugging, exception, deployment, sql-server-ce

I've deployed my application on a new machine, I've installed the Compact Edition Runtime and got a weird exception.
I coudln't locate any info about that on the web furthermore, ways to solve it.

Maybe you've encountered it?

This is the exception:

> Type : System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException, System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=3.5.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91
>
> Message : The specified locale is not installed on this machine. Make sure you install the appropriate language pack. [ LCID = 1037 ]
>
> Source : SQL Server Compact ADO.NET Data Provider
> Errors : System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeErrorCollection
> HResult : -2147467259
> NativeError : 25130
> Data : System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal

Thanks,
Ariel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well what ever solved it was to install support for left-to-right languages.
But it still puzzles me what is the reason for that. we use no such languages either in the app or the db. 
I shall need to investigate.

Answer (score 0):

It's complaining about the locale.  The website in your profile indicates you're from Italy.  Is it possible you installed the italian version on an english machine, or vice versa?

Comment: I'm positive an English version was installed. (and il stand for Israel :))

Comment: My bad on the .il - Italy is .it, so I should have known :(

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be related to Hebrew localization. LCID 1037 is the Hebrew locale identifier.

Comment: if the locale on the development machine and deployment machine are different. It might be the cause. however far fetch it seem.